# Facebook open graph publish stream/actions meta tags as params?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to pass: og:url, og:title, og:image, og:description to rest without declaring it on metatags in an html page?

```
FB.api('/me/recipebox:cook', 'post', 
  { recipe : 'http://www.example.com/pumpkinpie.html' });
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/

I'm using push state/single-page application and it will be more easy using internal params.

Something like:

```
FB.api('/me/recipebox:cook', 'post', 
  { recipe : my_json });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to pass: og:url, og:title, og:image, og:description to rest without declaring it on metatags in an html page?

No, because an Open Graph Object *is* a URL.

Comment: but how can I make more than one publish actions with different objects on the same page, dynamically? Create an iframe or something like that?

Comment: 1 object = 1 URL. Multiple objects = multiple URLs.